# Handling page requests using Java Server

Tags: java, sockets

I have made a Multithreaded server which listens to clients. Now I want to handle the browser requests the client enters on the browser. And return the appropriate page.

For example:
localhost:8080\fahad.html

returns a html page or shows 404 error. where should I put the html pages and what is the way to do it. I am using Eclipse to make the server> i think servlets might solve my problem but importing the servlet libraries. Guidance will be apreciated.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 


public class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable {
 Socket client;
 MultiThreadServer(Socket csocket) {
   this.client = csocket;
 }

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
   ServerSocket server = null;
   try { 
      server = new ServerSocket(8000);
     } 
     catch (IOException e)
     { 
      System.out.println(e);
     }
   System.out.println("Listening");
   while (true) {
      Socket client = server.accept();
      System.out.println("Connected");
      new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(client)).start();
   }
}
public void run() {
   try {

      String line;
      DataInputStream is;
      PrintStream os; 
      is = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
      line = is.readLine(); 
      os.println(line);

      try{
         client.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {}
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: You have code pulled from a basic hello world type mutlithreaded socket example. What, if anything, have you bothered to try on your own?

Comment: This is because I am in the learning phase :)

Comment: So you learning is by asking us to show you how to do it? That isn't how this site works. Especially when the entirety of your code was copied from someone else's example.

Comment: Don't drag  me into an argument my friend. You want to help, please do, else just don't. I am a newbie and will learn after seeing things once.

Comment: Nobody is going to write a tutorial for you, good luck.